# Calculating Distance and Time on a network without the use of ArcGIS Network Analyst

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, distance, network-analyst, network

I'm trying to calculate a distance and time for walking commuters (about 30,000 records) on a street network (NYC Lion).  I have a starting and ending address for each record that have been geocoded.  As far as I know I don't have an ArcGIS Network Analyst extension license at the moment (maybe there's a free trial?) so I'm curious if anyone knows how to do this without Network Analyst.  I have QGIS but I'm not sure if you can batch process records in this capacity.

Comment: Network analysis in Arc requires a Network Analyst extension license. If you don't have it, you could try taking a look at pgrouting in QGIS. It's worth pointing out that per your description, you're looking at 30k route solves regardless of which software you're using (so you would need to batch/model either way *or* solve for a tremendous number of routes and filter the result). Is this a commercial or personal/student purpose? You can get NA for $100 a year (along with a lot of other extensions) with a personal license of Arc.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Urban Network Analysis toolbox download from City Form Lab.

Link to Download/site: http://cityform.mit.edu/projects/urban-network-analysis.html

Comment: Thanks Cameron, This toolbox looks really interesting but it requires Network Analyst

Comment: Try this link: http://cityform.mit.edu/projects/una-rhino-toolbox . This provides a way to work within Rhino 3D (which can be downloaded for free). There are videos within the link that explain how to export and import data into the rhino software and use the UNA toolbox. This is the only way around that I have found so far.

Comment: Let me know how that works.